# CI/CD Sitecore challenge: going from "wipe" to "overwrite"

Tags: powershell-extensions, tds, continuous-integration

We are set to release a large Sitecore-based system in a week.  Presently the CI/CD process works by effectively republishing *everything* from a `git` repository as the source (we use TDS for day-to-day development merging and update package generation).  It does this by following these steps, implemented as Powershell scripts calling into SPE:

1. Wipe both `master` and `web` databases (recursive `Remove-Item`);
2. Install two update packages (templates and content), using `UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx`;
3. Publish all items (recursive `Publish-Item`).

The whole process takes in the region of 2.5 hours to complete (we are using Sitecore 8.1, update 3).  The problem is that once live, we cannot afford to have downtime--perhaps a little downtime (minutes) is acceptable, early in the morning, but hours is something that the business have said they are not willing to accept.  Step 1 above essentially guarantees that the site will be down for a significant amount of time.

Our current "best" solution, given the short time we have is to simply do away with step 1 above, and just install the update packages (electing to overwrite items if they already exist).  *In theory*, since typically we don't expect there to be many changes from deploy to deploy, we would at least be able to create the impression that the site is not down during the deploy.

The problem with our proposed short-term fix is that we can't be sure that an "overwite" won't break things (due to potential loss of item relationship integrity).

In following the "overwrite" approach, will the inter-item relationship integrity be maintained?  I am aware of the fact that there will be orphan items and/or item graphs, but that should be okay, at least in the short term, since I am not expecting the stale items to influence the functionality of the site.

Comment: where are the environments located, Paas/Iaas or on-prem?

Comment: @SivaSankar, all in Azure (IaaS), but why would that make a difference?

Comment: Have you seen this for removing tree of items? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2186/95

Comment: Another thought is you won't package up content after go live. It's a CMS so content is volatile and managed by the Editors. Also, Unicorn, Rainbow, and Sitecore Sidekick can help tremendously.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWest , yes I know, that's how we'd obviously like to do things, and that's what's been sold the customer (again).  Unfortunately, for some time after go-live developer-level artifacts (e.g., templates) will remain volatile.  This really is an interim solution, and we understand that; all I need to know is will what I'm proposing above work without breaking things?

Comment: I imagine the Publishing is very expensive and what impacts CD the most. May only be feasible if you use the Sitecore Publishing Service, which may require a newer version than what you are on. Perhaps time each step that impacts the CD and that may pinpoint what must change first.

Comment: Given that you are *always overwriting* it essentially means you can put the CMS into "read-only mode" at the moment, i.e. any changes made by users would be wiped out at next deploy. (This is a strange situation, but you have your reasons). You should also consider not wiping everything and using the [Delta Deploy option TDS](http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#general). This will mean smaller package install and publish (use incremental option).

Comment: We use unicorn for our ci/cd pipeline for everything but content.  Content itself is all done in the production environment by authors with their own workflow.  I am wondering why you would want to even consider wiping the master and web db on a deployment in the first place?